# How do I multiply matrix with vector and get result in matrix?

Tags: matlab, octave

Suppose I have a matrix:

```
A = [ a, b, c;
      d, e, f ];
```

and a vector:

```
b = [ x;
      y;
      z ];
```

What I want is resultant matrix as:

```
C = [ a*x, b*y, c*z;
      d*x, e*y, f*z ];
```

How can I do this?
Essentially, I want to multiply matrix (dimension: mxn) with a vector (nx1) and get resultant matrix mxn.

As requested in comments (using octave version `3.8.0`):

```
octave> A = [ 1,2,3;4,5,6]; B=[10;20;30];
octave> A*B
ans =

   140
   320

octave> A.*B
error: product: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x3, op2 is 3x1)
octave> bsxfun(@times, A, B)
error: bsxfun: nonconformant dimensions: 2x3 and 3x1
```

Comment: Did you try multiplying them?

Comment: b is not a scalar. It is a matrix or a colum vector as you prefer

Comment: @matzeri fixed typo.

Comment: Please see the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) of `.*`. If you're using MATLAB ≤ R2016a, you will need [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). In Octave and MATLAB  ≥ R2016b, you can directly use `.*` (after adjusting the dimensions)

Comment: @SardarUsama updated question with relevent information.

Comment: @SardarUsama bsxfun(@times, A, B') worked. I kindly request you to add it as answer.

Comment: `'` is complex conjugate transpose. You should be using simple transpose `.'` here because it is transpose that you're meant to take. Andy has already posted it. You can go ahead with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = [ 1,2,3;4,5,6];
B = [10;100;1000];
A.*B.'
ans =

     10    200   3000
     40    500   6000
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't notice your answer before my comment to the question. I am waiting for @SardarUsama 's input before I mark your answer as accepted answer.